# Cartesian to log polar coordinate conversion

Tags: cartesian

Hi I am trying to develop a java code that performs feature extraction in an image.
I extracted the keypoints from the image.
The next step is to divide the region around each keypoint into non overlapping regions using log polar coordinate system.
I browsed for the code to convert cartessian coordinates to log polar but i got the code in matlab only.
I need java code.
Can anyone help me

Comment: Log base what? e? 10? Angle too? Radians or degrees?

Comment: log base e and angle is radians

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is very straightforward in the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-polar_coordinates.

```
class Polar
{
    public double rho;
    public double theta;

    public void ToPolar(double x, double y)
    {
         rho = Math.log(Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y));
         theta = Math.atan2(y, x);
    }
}
```

Add anything else you need, but it's nothing special and it's very trivial to write. The above assumes your log is base e, and you're working in radians.

Comment: Please check if I am correct with what I am doing in the code.

Comment: If i want to divide the region around the point (100,200) then my x value will be 100 and y value will be 200. Is this correct? Also how many  sub -regions will I get?

Comment: Sorry not the code. Please check wether I am getting the concept correctly. If i want to divide the region around the point (100,200) then my x value will be 100 and y value will be 200. Is this correct? Also how many sub -regions will I get?